# Add text (not values) to stacked horizontal bar plot in R using base graphics

Tags: r, text, bar-chart

I am trying to create an infographic showing scores with one grouping factor and one identifying factor using a stacked barchart in R. I want to write the ID on top of the relevant section of the bar. All the answers I've come across discuss how to add the value of the bar as a label, not the row name.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
    id <- letters[seq(1,4)]
    groups <- LETTERS[seq(1,8)]
    scores <- matrix((c(0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,2)),ncol=8)
   row.names(scores) <- id
   par(mfrow=c(1, 1), mar=c(2, 5, 2, 2))
   bb <- barplot(scores, horiz = T, las = 2, cex.names = 0.5,xaxt="n", cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5, legend=F,main="Weekly Scores", space=0, border=NA)
```

I want something like this [Adding values to barplot of table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27466035/adding-values-to-barplot-of-table-in-r) 
but horizontal instead of vertical bars, and the ID text (a,b,c etc) in place of the values. I'd rather not use ggplot or any other package if possible (using packages limits user friendliness of code at work due to admin rights).

To make things more complicated, my ID values are (and have to remain so for the purposes of the graphic) sentence length.... I am currently wrapping them using  a function I found online:

```
# Write function to wrap labels
wrap.it <- function(x, len)
{ 
sapply(x, function(y) paste(strwrap(y, len), 
                          collapse = "\n"), 
     USE.NAMES = FALSE)
 }

# Call this function with a list or vector
 wrap.labels <- function(x, len)
 {
 if (is.list(x))
   {
  lapply(x, wrap.it, len)
   } else {
  wrap.it(x, len)
   }
 }
```

so I will want to "fit" the wrapped text into the bar. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Have you noticed your plot has 8 groups, and not 4? You're ploting the columns, not the rows, but some of them are all zeros. I'm saying this because you'd need 8 IDs, not 4. Maybe what you want is `t(scores)` inside the `barplot` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can add text an values. Modify as you desire.

```
id <- letters[seq(1,4)]
groups <- LETTERS[seq(1,8)]
scores <- matrix((c(2,0,7,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,2,0,0,8,0,2)),ncol=8)
row.names(scores) <- id

acsc=apply(scores,2,cumsum)
par(mfrow=c(1, 1), mar=c(2, 5, 2, 2))
bb <- barplot(scores, horiz = T, las = 2, cex.names = 0.5,xaxt="n",col=c("grey60","grey70","grey80","grey90"),
    cex.axis=0.5,cex.lab=0.5, legend=F,main="Weekly Scores", space=0, border=NA)
sapply(1:4,function(z)
text(acsc[z,]-.3,bb,labels=sapply(scores[z,],function(zr)ifelse(zr==0,"",paste(rownames(scores)[z],zr,sep="="))),cex=.8))
axis(2,at=bb,groups)
```

[image]